# Jquery doesn't send data to Spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

I have a javaEE application and i have a jquery form to add a user to database. I send fiekd values to my Spring controller, but for some reason the data isn't sent.
What is the issue?

I get the following exception in log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [login] in @RequestMapping
```

Form

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />            
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
 </fieldset>
</form:form>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Add user</button>
```

Script

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function() {
                    var login = $( '#login' );
                    var email = $( '#email' );
                    var  password = $( '#password' );
                    $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test",
                                data: "login=" + login + "&email=" + email + "&password="+ password,
                                success: function(){
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                    })
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void test(@PathVariable String login, @PathVariable String password, @PathVariable String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin(login);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setEmail(email);
    userService.create(user);
}
```

Comment: use spring form tags like `form:input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PathVariable` is for information embedded in the URL 'REST Style'.  e.g.,:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/user/{login}/password/{password}/email/{email}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

To read in regular old http parameters that are in the query string or post body the annotaton is `@RequestParam`, rather than `@PathVariable`.

```
public void test(@RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("email") String email) {
```

Also in your ajax, `data` is expecting, well, data.  If you want to format it as query string, it should be appended to the URL directly.  to put it in the body you would do:

```
data: {login:login ,email: email,password: password}
```

rather than format it as a query string.  You can also just use jQuery's `.serialize()` method on the form tag to easily send the entire form as if the submit button had been clicked.

Comment: I don't fully understand how i should do this. When i use @RequestParam i get all values as [object Object].

Comment: It will parse/bind the data into whatever (supported) type you declare for the method parameters.

Comment: I've tried to change it your way, but now nothing is inserted into database. I'm sorry, i'm only learning. Could you please explain more clearly how it works?

Comment: Did you also change the jquery to serialize the form body into the data element instead of format as a query string?

Answer (score -1):

Since it is POST request you have to use @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable

@PathVariable is for GET requests